# C# variable automatically rounds down, while it's set to round to 2 decimals

Tags: c#

Every time I run this it rounds `num13` down, which is not what I want. I want it to round to 2 decimal places. How do I make it round to 2 decimal places so that if I enter the correct answer, for example `10 / 4 == 2.50`, then `if (num12 == num13)` will evaluate to `true`? Right now `num13` evaluates to 2 instead of the expected 2.5.

```
Random NumberGen = new Random();
start6:
    int num10 = NumberGen.Next(1, 11);
    int num11 = NumberGen.Next(1, 11);

start5:
    if (num10 > num11)
    {
        Console.Write(num10 + " / " + num11 + " = ");
        decimal num12;
        num12 = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
        num12 = Math.Round(num12, 2);
        decimal num13;
        num13 = num10 / num11;
        num13 = Math.Round(num13, 2);
        if (num12 == num13)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            goto start;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("wrong answer, try again.");
            goto start5;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        goto start6;
    }
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373(v=vs.71).aspx) is your friend.

Comment: Integer division... `10/4 = 2` when dividing integers since the remainder is truncated.

Comment: Why do you use goto statements in c#?!?

Comment: I'd highly recommend avoiding `goto` at all costs.  There are a few places were it's considered generally acceptable to use `goto`, but they are very specific cases.  It creates very bad program flow.

Comment: thanks it worked, i'm stupid

Answer (score 3):

As surprising as it might sound,

```
decimal a = 10 / 4;
```

will yield `2`, not `2.5`. That's because the `/` operator performs an *integer division* if both its operands (`10` and `4`) are integers:

> When you divide two integers, the result is always an integer. *(Source: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b1ff23f.aspx))*

In your case, this can be fixed by making sure that one of your operands is *not* an integer:

```
decimal num13;
num13 = (decimal)num10 / num11;
```

*(And while you are at it: Please consider making your variable names more descriptive.)*

Comment: you suggested same answer, but before me :(

Answer (score 0):

You would have to initialize num10 and num11 as decimal or doubles initially as you will get an integer value when you divide two integers.

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal num13;
num13 = (decimal)num10 / num11;
```

Answer (score 0):

in one line

```
decimal num13=  Math.Round((decimal)num10 / num11, 2);
```